# Using XSLT to Eliminate a node based on one or more text values in XML for Mythtv

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given the sample (shortened) MythTV XML program guide:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:downloadResponse SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:ns1='urn:TMSWebServices'>
    <xtvdResponse xsi:type='ns1:xtvdResponse'>
    <messages xsi:type='ns1:messages'>
    <message>Your subscription will expire: 2017-07-25T05:40:43Z</message>
    </messages>
    <xtvd from='2016-06-28T00:00:01Z' to='2016-07-12T00:00:01Z' schemaVersion='1.3' xmlns='urn:TMSWebServices' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='urn:TMSWebServices http://dd.schedulesdirect.org/tech/xml/schemas/tmsxtvd.xsd'>
    <program id='MV000084150000'>
    <title>Across 110th Street</title>
    <mpaaRating>R</mpaaRating>
    <starRating>**+</starRating>
    <runTime>PT01H42M</runTime>
    <year>1972</year>
    <description>Mobsters and crooked police (Anthony Quinn, Yaphet Kotto) hunt three hoods who have robbed a mob operation in Harlem.</description>
    <advisories>
    <advisory>Adult Situations</advisory>
    <advisory>Language</advisory>
    <advisory>Violence</advisory>
    </advisories>
    </program>
    <program id='MV000083800000'>
    <title>Conan the Barbarian</title>
    <mpaaRating>R</mpaaRating>
    <starRating>***</starRating>
    <runTime>PT02H09M</runTime>
    <year>1982</year>
    <description>Pit fighter Conan (Arnold Schwarzenegger) sets out with a Mongol and a queen (Sandahl Bergman) to take his father&apos;s sword from a snake king (James Earl Jones).</description>
    <advisories>
    <advisory>Adult Situations</advisory>
    <advisory>Nudity</advisory>
    <advisory>Graphic Violence</advisory>
    </advisories>
    </program>
    </xtvd>
    </xtvdResponse>
    </ns1:downloadResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am trying to develop a XSLT that will remove a complete `<program>` node when the `<advisory>` contains the text "Nudity" or "Brief Nudity".

Here is what I've been trying, just to address "Nudity":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="program[descendant::advisory[text() = 'Nudity']]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...but it doesn't work on MythTV's XML, though if I try the same basic approach on much simpler XML, it works:

```
  <root>
<program>
<advisories>
<advisory>blabla</advisory>
</advisories>
</program>
<program>
<advisories>
<advisory>http://media.blabla.pdf</advisory>
</advisories>
</program> 
<program>
<advisories>
<advisory>http://media2.blabla.pdf</advisory>
</advisories>
</program> 
<program>
<advisories>
<advisory>http://media.otherblabla</advisory>
</advisories>
</program> 
</root>
```

When I run xsltproc to apply the XSLT on the simple XML with --verbose, I get some output (xsltEvalXPathPredicate: returns 1) I don't see from the MythTV XML, so I'm guessing there's some XPath technique I need to apply, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone advise what to do to solve this?  My intention is to document how to make a free program schedule filter so certain shows simply aren't offered/displayed on the MythTV listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node you're looking for is within namespace `urn:TMSWebServices`. You need to define it within your XSLT like `xmlns:tv="urn:TMSWebServices"`, and then use it within your XPath like

```
tv:program[descendant::tv:advisory[text() = 'Nudity']]
```

This same problem is addressed in other questions ([here's one I found quick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6363998/65839)), though I understand that it's tough to know what to search for if you're not familiar with XML namespaces and how they affect XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Cooper Jr. for such great help, here is the full XSLT to solve the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tv="urn:TMSWebServices">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="tv:program[descendant::tv:advisory[text() = 'Nudity' or text() = 'Brief Nudity']]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```